# How to add/sum values from separate lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, enumerate

I have a list of single digits that I want to sum together.

I started out with this:

```
d3 = [9,9,9,8]
d4 = [3,6,np.nan,10]

for i,j in enumerate(d3):
    add = [(d3[i]-d4[i])**2]
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following lists:

```
[36]
[9]
[nan]
[4]
```

However, I want the SUM of these numbers, while ignoring the NaN (desired output is 36+9+4):

Comment: `if not np.isnan(d4[i]) and not np.isnan(d3[i]):`?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 6):

For fast code in numpy, you want to avoid looping when possible.  Convert to numpy arrays (frankly, it's probably better to *start* with them, otherwise you lose every time you convert!), apply vector operations, and then use `np.nansum`:

```
In [9]: np.array(d3) - np.array(d4)
Out[9]: array([  6.,   3.,  nan,  -2.])

In [10]: (np.array(d3) - np.array(d4))**2
Out[10]: array([ 36.,   9.,  nan,   4.])

In [11]: np.nansum((np.array(d3) - np.array(d4))**2)
Out[11]: 49.0
```

For comparison, if we *start* with numpy arrays, it's much nicer to read:

```
In [14]: d3 = np.array(d3); d4 = np.array(d4)

In [15]: np.nansum((d3-d4)**2)
Out[15]: 49.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> d3 = [9,9,9,8]
>>> d4 = [3,6,np.nan,10]
>>> total = np.nansum([(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(d3, d4)])
49.0
```

## edit

Here are some tests to show how long this takes, using list, np.array's, and converting lists to np.array's on the fly:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> short_l1 = [9,9,9,8]
>>> short_l2 = [3,6,np.nan,10]
>>> long_l1 = short_l1 * 1000
>>> long_l2 = short_l2 * 1000

>>> short_a1 = np.array(short_l1)
>>> short_a2 = np.array(short_l2)
>>> long_a1 = np.array(long_l1)
>>> long_a2 = np.array(long_l2)

>>> %timeit np.nansum([(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(short_l1 , short_l2)])
9.1 µs ± 29.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.nansum((np.array(short_l1)-np.array(short_l2))**2)
12 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.nansum((short_a1-short_a2)**2)
9.07 µs ± 24.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.nansum([(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(long_l1 , long_l2)])
1.32 ms ± 15.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.nansum((np.array(long_l1)-np.array(long_l2))**2)
498 µs ± 3.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.nansum((long_a1-long_a2)**2)
48.7 µs ± 581 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see, you should definitely be doing what @DSM answered, it's **way** faster when your data size increases

Comment: No. This is _not_ the best way to do it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No point of changing it to numpy arrays, since there are other answers already showing that.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added some timing so OP can see why this is not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sum of the values in the list ignoring the NaN values, there is a built in function in numpy called `np.nansum()` that will ignore all NaN values:

```
d4 = [3,6,np.nan,10]
print(np.nansum(d4))
Out[110]: 19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([ np.nansum([x,y]) for x,y in zip(d3, d4) ])
```

alternatively, fitting to your code rather than request:

```
np.nansum([ (x-y)**2 for x,y in zip(d3, d4) ])
```

Answer (score 0):

What about ignoring the nan:

```
for i,j in enumerate(d3):
    if d3[i] != np.nan and d4[i] != np.nan:
        add = [(d3[i]-d4[i])**2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot operate numbers with null/nan objects/primitives.
Also you substract a pow value (????) not adding. 
For adding you have to:

```
d3 = [9,9,9,8]
d4 = [3,6,2,10]
add=None
for i,j in enumerate(d3):
    add = d3[i]+d4[i]
    print(add)
```

Comment: This is not useful to OP at all.